# ¿Como puedo consultar un modelo que esta en un modelo desde otro modelo? Laravel6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Perdón si no pude ser claro en la pregunta, es que no supe como explicarlo.

Estoy empezando en Laravel 6 y estoy aprendiendo sobre modelos. Relacione todos los modelos 1:N - N:N - 1:1 etc. La cosa es que tengo el modelo **Mantenimiento** que tiene una relacion **N:1** con **Vehiculo** y a su vez **Vehiculo** tiene una relacion **N:1** con **TipoVehiculo**.

- **Mantenimiento** ***N:1*** **Vehiculo**
- **Vehiculo** ***N:1*** **TipoVehiculo**

Quiero saber si puedo acceder a un campo de **TipoVehiculo** directamente desde el modelo **Mantenimiento** pasando por **Vehiculo**, o tal vez estoy hablando puras cosas sin sentido?

Así es como extraigo un dato de las dos tablas relacionadas:

```
$mantenimientos = App\Mantenimiento::findOrFail(1);
return $mantenimientos->vehiculos;
```

Me gustaria saber si puedo hacer algo asi:

```
$mantenimientos = App\Mantenimiento::findOrFail(1);
return $mantenimientos->vehiculos->tipoVehiculos;
introducir el código aquí
```

En mis modelos tengo algo como esto:

```
class Vehiculo extends Model { 
  public function tipovehiculos() 
  { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Tipovehiculo::class, 'id'); 
  } 
}
```

En el modelo Tipovehiculo tengo:

```
 class Tipovehiculo extends Model{ 
   public function vehiculos() 
   { 
     return $this->hasMany(Vehiculo::class, 'tipovehiculo_id'); 
   } 
 }
```

Tengo el mismo formato para relacionar los modelos Mantenimiento con Vehiculo, especificando sus respectivos campos

Luego la DB:

En mi tabla **mantenimientos** tengo los campos:

***id*** // **Observacion** // **vehiculo_id**

En mi tabla **vehiculos** tengo los campos:

***id*** // **Placa** // **marca** // **users_id** // **tipovehiculos_id**

Y finalmente en mi tabla **tipo_vehiculos**:

***id*** // **tipo**

Comment: Podrías mostrar cómo tienes definidas en los modelos la relaciones que mencionas *Mantenimiento N:1 Vehiculo" y "Vehiculo N:1 TipoVehiculo"? Me surge la duda porque cuando dices "me gustaría saber si puedo hacer algo así: `$mantenimientos->vehiculos->tipoVehiculos;`", pones todo en plural, pero sería 1 Mantenimiento, 1 Vehiculo y 1 TipoVehiculo, por lo que la respuesta sería "Sí, puedes. Pero tendría mas sentido que a las relaciones `belongsTo` las nombres en singular."

Comment: En mi Modelo **Vehiculo** tengo `class Vehiculo extends Model
{ public function tipovehiculos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tipovehiculo::class, 'id');
    }
}`
Y luego en mi modelo **Tipovehiculo** tengo 
`class Tipovehiculo extends Model
{
    public function vehiculos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehiculo::class, 'tipovehiculo_id');
    }
}`
Asi es como tengo la relacion **Vehiculo N:1 Tipovehiculo**
Lo que tenia escrito en plural es en referencia a los nombres de las funciones @porloscerros-Ψ

Comment: Está bien, a eso iba, al nombre de las funciones, pues tiene más sentido que sea `tipovehiculo()` que `tipovehiculos()`, ya que es uno solo. En realidad le puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras, pero puede confundir. Entonces `$mantenimientos->vehiculos->tipoVehiculos;` no te funciona? Te da algún error? Podrías mostrar también la función `vehiculos()` del modelo Mantenimiento? También sería útil saber los nombres de las llaves foráneas de cada tabla. Mejor si lo agregas a la pregunta, que es más fácil de leer que en un comentario.

Comment: Ya veo la estructura no se parece a la que asumí al escribir mi respuesta, edito entonces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con tu edición estoy entendiendo que tu orden de tablas es:

- tipo_vehiculos
- vehiculos
- Mantenimientos

Entonces considerando lo anterior tu escenario parece ajustarse a la relación **hasManyTrough** que ofrece Laravel a través de 
Eloquent de este modo:

Como tratamos de obtener datos de la tabla tipo_vehiculo que directamente no se encuentra relacionada con el modelo Mantenimiento.

Entonces nos apoyamos de la tabla intermedia que en este caso es: **vehiculos**, creamos un modelo llamado `Mantenimiento`, el cual por dentro de los paréntesis recibirá 2 parámetros:

- Parámetro 1 es el modelo objetivo o destino
- Parámetro 2 es el modelo intermedio o a través del cual pasaremos para lograr obtener datos
- Clave foránea en la tabla intermedia que en este caso la nombre `tipovehiculo_id` en la tabla **vehiculos**
- Clave primaria en la tabla origen que sería en este ejemplo **mantenimiento**
- Clave primaria en la tabla objetivo que en este ejemplo sería **tipo_vehiculos**

**Construcción de relación**

```
class Mantenimiento extends Model
{
    public function tipoVehiculo()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(TipoVehiculo::class,
                                     Vehiculo::class,
                                     'tipovehiculo_id',
                                     'id',
                                     'id');
    }
}
```

Para el caso de la consulta podemos invocar al método tipoVehiculo ubicamos algún registro por su id y entonces obtenemos todos los tipos de vehiculo asociados a ese mantenimiento

Al final de la consulta encadenamos el nombre del método que definimos mas arriba con la relación tiene muchos a través de....

**Consulta**

```
$data = Mantenimiento::findOrFail($id)->tipoVehiculo;
```

**Referencia**

- [Relación `hasManyTrough` en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respues tan util @Aprendiz. Hice la relacion hasManyThroug. Sin embargo al momento de realizar la consulta no devuleve ningun dato. Mi codigo quedo algo como esto:

`public function tipovehiculos()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Tipovehiculo::class, Vehiculo::class, 'tipovehiculo_id', 'id');
    }`

el cuarto parametro que estoy mandando se supone es el **FK** del modelo **Vehiculo** que lo relaciona con el modelo **Tipovehiculo**, luego el quinto parametro que mando **id** se supone es la **PK** del modelo **Tipovehiculo**

Comment: No puedo evitar pensar que estoy haciendo mal lo del cuarto y quinto parametro y es por eso que no me devuelve datos en la consulta.
La consulta que estoy realizando es la siguiente:
`$tipo = App\Mantenimiento::findOrFail($id)->tipovehiculos->first()`
y no retorna nada, ni errores. @aprendiz

Comment: @RastaBlue puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar los nombres de columnas de cada una?

Comment: @RastaBlue checa la actualización

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, efectivamente me faltaba agregar un quinto parámetro para poder realizar la consulta. Gracias por la paciencia.